# Angular2 redirect from static method

Tags: redirect, angular, routes, static-methods, navigateurl

Hi i have 'static class' Utils with only static methods (helpers):

```
export class Utils {    
     static doSomethingAndRedirect() {
         ...doo something...
         redirectTo->'/home'     
     }

}
```

So how `redirectTo` code should look like?

Comment: You need a reference to the applications injector to be able to acquire a reference to the router. Just don't use a static method.

Comment: i will be satisfy when someone give me answer also in pure js without angular2. Utils is my helper STATIC class - and I don't want to change it. Redirectin is so easy in js - there is a problem with angular2 ?

Comment: You try to stroke Angular2 against the grain, therefore no surprise you're not happy with it ;-) Angular2 is a new framework. Almost nothing about Angular1 applies to it.

Comment: Why angular2 not support static methods?

Comment: Because they would need to build the whole framework in a different way and this would cause it to be less testable while testability is a main priority.

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong approach to the usecase you are trying to solve. Have a look at `ngrx/store` and `ngrx/effects`.

In short, you define actions and reducers which modify the state of your app. Next, you can react to different actions with different side-effects (`ngrx/effects`), for example in my app I have got:

- Actions: LoginAction and LoginSuccessAction
- Effects: when LoginSuccessAction is triggered, my effect redirects to `/dashboard` component

This makes for nice separation of concerns:

- views display the current state and dispatch actions that change the state
- actions specify what happens in the app
- reducers specify what changes to state occur for different actions
- effects specify what side-effects occur for certain actions

Comment: Can you give more concrete solution for case described in my question? - How i should use ngrx in my Utils static class?

Comment: ngrx is a whole solution for managing state in the app, depending on your usecase it might be overkill. If you just want a utility class for small, common tasks, a `UtilityService` injected with `Router` might be want you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I found in my case was just... add parameter 'router' into static function argument list:

```
 static doSomethingAndRedirect(router) {
     ...doo something...

     router.navigateByUrl('home'); // redirect
 }
```

This is a kind of compromise between static helper convenience and non-static "angular way".